# My manager suggest me to find a new job. How should I deal with it?

Tags: human-resources, quitting

I am SDE in IT company and honestly I did not get good performance review.

My manager told me in our 1:1 that he thought I may get fired in next performance review meeting and he suggested me to start finding job. He is a very nice person but lack of management experience.

I little bit panic, start to search job and use some PTO. I am afraid that I do it pretty obvious that my co-worker may notice that I am job hunting.

Anyway, the performance review is in two weeks and I have couple on-site scheduled before it, but no guarantee that I can have a new job.

I am sure I will not get good performance review, but I am not sure I will be fired or not, I am not sure I can get an offer before the review or not.

Any suggestion for me? Should I just quit the job before fine to avoid bad record?

Comment: Prove your manager that he is wrong and work hard to get a positive review !

Comment: @Weedoze if your manager has already said that you'll probably be fired in your next review, that suggests it's already out of his hands. Working hard now sounds like a case of "if you run, you'll just die tired".

Comment: We do not answer questions that ask for general advice, but if you specifically want to know "should I quit before the performance review so they can't fire me?", I think that's answerable. Do you want to focus on that part? Or can you clarify what other goal you might have that we can help with?

Comment: What does SDE stand for in this case?

Answer (score 16):

**Look for a new job, but don't quit.** Yea a bad performance review can end up biting you in the behind sometime in the future but qualification to unemployment benefits wins - in my opinion. (YMMV - I don't know what rules apply where you are)

This might be a scare tactic by your manager. But who wants that kind of manager? Pushing people to excel is one thing, asking them to look for a new job is another. **You want to look for a new job.**

This might be a tactic to get rid of a worker that will pass a performance review but that the manager does not want to be on the team. You don't want to stay hired to a manager that does not want you on the team. **You want to look for a new job.**

This might be what it is at face value, an overly friendly manager trying to give fair warning. **You want to look for a new job.**

At least when (if) the performance review goes south you have had a couple more weeks to hunt. If it goes well, then no time has been lost (he specifically told you to look for a new job - take advantage of it) and you might actually stand with more options than before.

In either case, whatever you choose, good luck!

Comment: **This.** I can't speak for the whole world (obviously) but here in Canada it's not uncommon for people to move around. Companies will usually frame a dismissal as a lay off rather than a termination (unless you **really cocked up.**) Having a few lay offs on your resume won't slow you down at all these days, especially in tech. So, take the time you've been given to job hunt and if you don't find anything in time, take the severance and keep moving forward. I would, however, add that he should continue job hunting even if he doesn't get fired at the next review - it might still happen later.